# Propagate nested object change notifications to upper level in Realm

Tags: swift, realm

I am aware that this is an old question and that there have been numerous discussions about this topic.

I recall that a member of the Realm development team mentioned that nested object notification propagation is not available in the default SDK due to performance optimization concerns, as some users may create very **deeply nested objects**. If I understand correctly, this feature is not included by default, but it is possible to implement by yourself.

I would like to build an extension that adds this missing functionality, allowing me to observe nested objects. If anyone has already done this work and is willing to share, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
final class ParentObject: Object {
    @Persisted var embeddedObject: SomeEmbeddedObject?
}

final class SomeEmbeddedObject: EmbeddedObject {
   @Persisted var text: String = ""
}

parentObject.someObserveMethod { ... } // Notifies about changes within an embedded object.

// write transaction
parentObject.embeddedObject!.text = "Hello World"
```

Comment: Are you saying that changes to an object embedded within a parent object would not trigger a notification for the observed parent object? If so, that is untrue. Changes are propagated up to the parent object.

Comment: @RobC actually its not:)
Changes to embedded object do not trigger notifications to parent observer